# Abstract away the type in a static method in a non-static class

Tags: c#, static, abstraction

I have a class like this:

```
public class LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType,
                                                    Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var meta = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            return meta;
        if (meta.DisplayName == null)
            GetLocalizedDisplayName(meta, propertyName);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(meta.DisplayName))
        {
            string resource = string.Format("{0}_{1}", meta.ContainerType.Name, meta.PropertyName).ToLower();
            meta.DisplayName = string.Format("[{0}]", resource);
        }
        return meta;
    }

    private static void GetLocalizedDisplayName(ModelMetadata meta, string propertyName)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof (i18n));
        CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        string resource = string.Format("{0}_{1}", meta.ContainerType.Name, meta.PropertyName).ToLower();
        meta.DisplayName = rm.GetString(resource, culture);
    }
}
```

I want to abstract away the line

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof (i18n));
```

I want to make this class indenpendent of the type `i18n`. I want to be able to specify the type for the resource manager at construction/initialization, making the class more universal and put it in a standalone class library.

What are my options? Can it be done with a static class or do I have to have non-static class? Or can I just leave the way it is, abstract the `rm` as class field and initialize it in the constructor?

Thank you

UPDATE: Please note the class will most likely be used in various ASP.NET MVC sites in global.asax.cs like this:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted();
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
}
```

I am never actually referencing or using this class directly, ASP.NET MVC does everything under the hood.

Comment: What advantage does this have over simply having `DisplayAttribute` declarations on model properties with a resource type and resource name specified (assuming `DisplayAttribute` works properly for the framework you're using (e.g. it works ok in MVC3, but not MVC2))

Comment: huge advantage because it allows us to skip DisplayAttribute altogether and defaults to this Model MetaData provider for providing the resource strings - I find it very time consuming to write attributes especially the ones with references to the Resource names. And this is working perfectly, now I'd just like to make it more generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the class generic:

```
    public class LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider<T> : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType,
                                                    Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var meta = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            return meta;
        if (meta.DisplayName == null)
            GetLocalizedDisplayName<T>(meta, propertyName);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(meta.DisplayName))
        {
            string resource = string.Format("{0}_{1}", meta.ContainerType.Name, meta.PropertyName).ToLower();
            meta.DisplayName = string.Format("[{0}]", resource);
        }
        return meta;
    }

    private static void GetLocalizedDisplayName<T>(ModelMetadata meta, string propertyName)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof (T));
        CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        string resource = string.Format("{0}_{1}", meta.ContainerType.Name, meta.PropertyName).ToLower();
        meta.DisplayName = rm.GetString(resource, culture);
    }
```

And set it up like this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider<i18n>();
```

Comment: this could work but check out the updated code I provided where I wire up the class to the current ModelMetaDataProvider. I have to get the T type into the class somehow.

Comment: I updated your code with the additional modifications for the code to be complete. Since you guided me in the right direction I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming type `i18n` is consistent across the entire application, then you have a few options, which all are forms of **Inversion of Control** / **Dependency Injections**.  The simplest thing is to do something like this:

```
public class LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    private static readonly Type _i18nType = I18nTypeProvider.GetI18nType();

    private static void GetLocalizedDisplayName(ModelMetadata meta, string propertyName)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(_i18nType);
        CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        string resource = string.Format("{0}_{1}", meta.ContainerType.Name, meta.PropertyName).ToLower();
        meta.DisplayName = rm.GetString(resource, culture);
    }
}
```

Where `I18nTypeProvider.GetI18nType` is another static method elsewhere that has the logic to find the appropriate type and return it at runtime (i.e., reflection).

An even better option is to use an dependency injection product like Managed Extensibility Framework or NInject.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx

http://ninject.org/